# $a_0 = 5/2$. $a_k = (a_{k-1})^{2} - 2$ for $k\geq1. \prod_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1-1/a_k\right)}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Some hints for the evaluation of this infinite product would be appreciated.

$a_0 = 5/2$.

$a_k = (a_{k-1})^{2} - 2$ for $k\geq1.$

Evaluate : $$\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1-1/a_k\right)}.$$

I tried finding $a_1$ $a_2$ and so on, and then multiplying them to see if I could find an easier sequence to solve but I could no proceed any further, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a little improved your text. In particular, I have changed the term "multiplication" into the term "product", which is usual in such cases (see the tag "infinite product")

Comment: I don't understand why have people downvoted this.

Comment: I haven't downvoted your question. Nevertheless, I understand that some colleagues have done it. When you say "some initial data", it seems you are not understanding your own question ! It is at the root of the definition of your infinite product.

Comment: Any help would be great.

Comment: @JeanMarie Any help would be appreciated, I have been at it for an hour but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: This product looks to converge towards 3/7 but I have no proof of it.

Comment: @JeanMarie wow you got it correct, but how? how did you guess it was going to converge to 3/7

Comment: Obtaining the value of an infinite product is often impossible, and if it is possible can be very difficult. Compared to series, infinite products are much more difficult to tackle.

Comment: @JeanMarie but how did you know it was going to converge to 3/7

Comment: I guessed the value 3/7 through the observation of the first terms.

Comment: @JeanMarie by the way this question was asked in a class 12 maths paper.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat please take a look at this.

Comment: see the answer (in fact a hint) I am going to write.

Comment: @JeanMarie you were talking about giving a hint.

Comment: can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a kind of simplification of the problem, not an answer.

Nevertheless, the kind of methodology that is involved (introducing a geometric progression) is good to be known because it can be used in several cases.

If we write the recurrence relationship under the form:

$$\dfrac{a_k}{2}=2\left(\dfrac{a_{k-1}}{2}\right)^2-1$$

and we place it in comparison with relationship:

$$\tag{1}\cosh(2t)=2\cosh(t)^2-1$$

we can set $a_0=2\cosh(b_0)$, $a_1=2\cosh(2 b_0)$, $a_2=2\cosh(4b_0)$...

with $b_k=b_02^k$ , and $b_0=(\cosh)^{-1}(5/4)$

(a **geometric sequence**) we have:

$$a_k=2\cosh(b_k)$$

the infinite product becomes:

$$\tag{2}\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2 \cosh(b_k)}\right)}$$

I am rather confident that a progress has been made, and that the limit $3/7$ that we have guessed can be obtained by working on the new expression (2), for example by connecting it to the known result:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\cosh\left(\dfrac{z}{2^k}\right)=\dfrac{\sinh(z)}{z}$$

(http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cosh/introductions/Cosh/05/ShowAll.html)

Remark: Relationship (1) has a mirror formula $\cos(2t)=2\cos(t)^2-1$ in circular trigonometry. We haven't use it because all the $a_k$s are $>1$.

---

**Edit**: I have had a closer look at the first values of $a_n$:

$$a_0=\dfrac{5}{2}, \ \ a_1=\dfrac{17}{4}, \ \ a_2=\dfrac{257}{16}, \ \ a_3=\dfrac{65537}{256}, \cdots$$

Something has striken me: the numerators and the denominators involve particular powers of two ("powers of two that are themselves powers of 2").

More precisely, we can conjecture, and it is readily verified, that:

$$a_{n-1}=\dfrac{2^{(2^{n})}+1}{2^{(2^{n-1})}}$$

I haven't gone beyond that, but it seems a good track for further investigations.

Comment: thanks for your time but unfortunately hyperbolic trigonometric functions are not in my syllabus

Comment: Sorry about that. Could you say why this question about infinite products ? Is it in your syllabus ?

Comment: yes it is a question of our test paper.

Comment: Woo, what do your lecturer awaits as an answer ? May I ask you which syllabus you follow, and in which educational system ?

Comment: I am preparing for a competitive exam and it has quite an extensive syllabus we were taught to solve these kind of questions in the chapter "sequences and series"

Comment: thanks, I will see what I can do from here.

Comment: You may wish to see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2548319), Jean Marie and @Gem.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art Interesting indeed.

Answer (score -1):

$a_0 = 5/2  = (2^2+1)/2$

$a_1 = a_0^2 - 2 = 17/4 = (2^4+1)/2^2 $

Let $a_n = (X^4+1)/X^2, X = 2^{2^(n-1)} $

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{k=0}^\infty (1-1/a_k) & = & \lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k-1}{a_k}\\
& = & \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_0-1}{a_0} \frac{a_1-1}{a_1} \frac{a_2-1}{a_2} \cdots \frac{a_n-1}{a_n} \\
& = & \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2^2-2+1}{2^2+1} \frac{4^2-4+1}{4^2+1} \frac{16^2-16+1}{16^2+1} \cdots \frac{X^2-X+1}{X^2+1} \\
& = & \lim_{x\to \infty} (2^2-1)/2^2+2+1 (X^4+X^2+1)/X^4-1 \\
& = & 3/7
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: @JeanMarie Is this right or is there any mistake?

Comment: I dont understand the last lines. How do you arrive at 3/7 ?

Comment: I've tidied up the MathJax as far as I was sure what the intended precedence was, but I haven't a clue what's going on in the penultimate line.

Comment: @Peter Taylor As I have said, groomed or not, since the beginning, this is not a proof.