# Is the link between Stern's diatomic sequence and binary subsequences genuine or a coincidence with exceptions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binary, farey-sequences

In a sister stack, [Martin Ender](//math.stackexchange.com/users/50421/martin-ender) raised a question about the following function:

> Let's define a function $f(N)$ on the integers via the following algorithm. We'll use $N = 38$ as an example:
>
> 1. Get the binary representation of $N$: $[1,0,0,1,1,0]$.
> 2. Take all *subsequences* of this list. These don't need to be contiguous, so $[1,1,1]$ is a valid subsequence, for example. Don't forget to include the empty subsequence: $$\{[], [1], [0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [1,0], ..., [1,0,1,1], \ldots, [1,0,0,1,1,0]\}$$
> 3. Convert each subsequence back to an integer by treating it as a list of bits. $[]$ should become zero: $$\{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, \ldots, 11, \ldots, 38\}$$
> 4. Count how many distinct values you get. The distinct values in this case are: $$\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 18, 19, 22, 38\}$$ That's $17$. This is $f(N)$.
>
> ...
>
> This sequence appears to be identical to [A007306](//oeis.org/A007306), except that the index is off-by-one (A007306 starts with an additional 1)

Is it genuinely the case that $f(N) = \textrm{A007306}(N+1)$, or is that just a coincidence which holds for a lot of numbers but has exceptions?

Answer (score 6):

It is genuinely the case that $f(n) = \textrm{A007306}(n+1)$.

To start with, let's take the observation

> Except for the initial one, this is the odd bisection of [A002487](//oeis.org/A002487). - Franklin T. Adams-Watters, May 25 2015

We're quite happy to discard the initial one, because that solves the offset problem! A002487 is Stern's diatomic sequence and has the simple recurrence $$\begin{eqnarray}\textrm{A002487}(0) & = & 0 \\
\textrm{A002487}(1) & = & 1 \\
\textrm{A002487}(2n) & = & \textrm{A002487}(n) \\
\textrm{A002487}(2n+1) & = & \textrm{A002487}(n) + \textrm{A002487}(n+1)\end{eqnarray}$$

Since we want to bisect it, let's define $N(k) = \textrm{A002487}(2k)$ and $D(k) = \textrm{A002487}(2k+1)$ (for numerator and denominator respectively). Then we have $$\begin{eqnarray}N(0) & = & 0\\
D(0) & = & 1\\
N(2k) & = & N(k) \\
D(2k) & = & N(k) + D(k) \\
N(2k+1) & = & D(k) \\
D(2k+1) & = & D(k) + N(k+1)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Borrowing another observation from OEIS,

> $(\textrm{A002487}(n-1) + \textrm{A002487}(n+1))/\textrm{A002487}(n) = \textrm{A037227}(n)$ for $n \ge 1$. - Peter Bala, Feb 07 2017

and since $\textrm{A037227}(2k+1) = 1$ for all $k$, we have $N(k) + N(k+1) = D(k)$ and so we can rewrite that last case as $$D(2k+1) = 2D(k) - N(k)$$

---

Now, let's consider $f(n)$ as defined in the OP. Let $S_n$ be the set of distinct values obtained in step 4. The subsequences which generate $S_{2k+i}$ with $i \in \{0,1\}$ are the subsequences which generate $S_k$ and each of those subsequences with an $i$ appended, and so we have an iterative definition: $$\begin{eqnarray}S_0 & = & \{0\} \\
S_{2k} & = & S_k \cup \{2x \mid x \in S_k\} \\
S_{2k+1} & = & S_k \cup \{2x+1 \mid x \in S_k\}
\end{eqnarray}$$

We can partition $S_n$ into four subsets and hence partition $f(n) = |S_n|$ into a four-tuple $(a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n)$ where $$\begin{eqnarray}
a_n = |\{x \mid x \in S_n \wedge 2x \in S_n \wedge 2x+1 \not\in S_n \}| \\
b_n = |\{x \mid x \in S_n \wedge 2x \not\in S_n \wedge 2x+1 \in S_n \}| \\
c_n = |\{x \mid x \in S_n \wedge 2x \in S_n \wedge 2x+1 \in S_n \}| \\
d_n = |\{x \mid x \in S_n \wedge 2x \not\in S_n \wedge 2x+1 \not\in S_n \}| \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Then we get a simple recurrence $$\begin{eqnarray}(a_0, b_0, c_0, d_0) & = & (1, 0, 0, 0) \\
(a_{2k}, b_{2k}, c_{2k}, d_{2k}) & = & (a_k + d_k, 0, b_k + c_k, b_k + d_k) \\
(a_{2k+1}, b_{2k+1}, c_{2k+1}, d_{2k+1}) & = & (0, b_k + d_k, a_k + c_k, a_k + d_k)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Clearly $c_k = d_k$ for all $k$, which simplifies things slightly.

Define $\nu_k = b_k + c_k$ and $\delta_k = a_k + b_k + 2 c_k = f(k)$. Then we have $$\begin{eqnarray}\nu_0 &= & 0 \\
\delta_0 & = & 1 \\
\nu_{2k} & = & b_k + c_k = \nu_k \\
\delta_{2k} & = & a_k + 2b_k + 3c_k = \nu_k + \delta_k \\
\nu_{2k+1} & = & a_k + b_k + 2c_k = \delta_k \\
\delta_{2k+1} & = & 2a_k + b_k + 3c_k = 2 \delta_k - \nu_k
\end{eqnarray}$$

Thus $(\nu_k, \delta_k)$ follows the same recurrence as $N(k), D(k)$ from the same initial conditions, and hence is identical. QED.

---

A more combinatorial proof would be nice. I wonder whether an alternative approach can be found in Calkin and Wilf's alternate bit set theorem, which certainly seems conceptually linked.

Comment: [Calkin and Wilf paper](http://cecas.clemson.edu/~janoski/reu/2010/latestversion.pdf) for anyone who wants to tackle the suggestion in the postscript.

Comment: Could you provide the link to the question in the "sister" stack ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11547/194 , but I don't know how long before it's deleted. Codegolf is different.

Comment: As you are interested by sequences, may I ask you to look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2140495) about a sequence that is needed for an infinite product. You will see that I have tried to find and answer, and an explanation for convergence to a very simple value. But I have not succeded [don't take care of the "answer" of the OP which defies the laws of mathematical reasoning...]